# Finding person with most frequent hit

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm new to SQL and am trying to learn it. A problem that occurred to me was how to find the maximum number of specific occurrences for a person in a table. I'm not sure how the query would compare each ID with another ID and keep track of the count. Poor explanation, but here is a dataset that will hopefully make it more clear.

```
players:
+--------+--------+
| pid    | name   |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | Tom    |
| 2      | Sam    |
| 3      | Dan    |
+--------+--------+

scores:
+--------+--------+--------+
| sid    | pid    | result |
+--------+--------+--------+
| 1      | 1      | miss   |
| 2      | 1      | hit    |
| 3      | 3      | hit    |
| 4      | 2      | miss   |
| 5      | 3      | hit    |
| 6      | 3      | hit    |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

The expected answer would be pid = 3, name = Dan because he had the most hits out of all the other players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select
  p.pid,
  p.name
From (
  Select
    p.pid,
    p.name,
    count(*)
  From
    players p
      inner join
    scores s On
      p.pid = s.pid
  Where
    result = 'hit'
  Group By
    p.pid,
    p.name
  Order By
    count(*) Desc
  ) p
Where 
  rownum = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03ba0/22

Comment: The sqlfiddle is giving the result of 1, Tom. It should be 3, Dan.

Comment: @user1834372 Oops, forgot that Oracle applies rownum before order, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a2d8/26)

```
select  pid, hits from(
    Select p.pid, count(*) as hits FROM players p
    JOIN scores s
         ON p.pid = s.pid AND s.result = 'hit'
    GROUP BY p.pid
    ORDER By count(*) DESC
)
Where rownum <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a solution:

```
select
  players.pid,
  players.name
from
  scores inner join players
  on scores.pid = players.pid
  and scores.result = 'hit'
group by players.pid, players.name
having count(*)=(select max(cnt)
                 from
                   (select pid, count(*) as cnt
                    from scores
                    where result='hit'
                    group by pid) t)
```

Notice that this will return more than one player if they all have the same number of hits. And notice also that if a player is present in scores table but not in players table, it will not show.